# Powershell FileSystemWatcher Error after first instance

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a directory I want to watch.  When any file is added to the directory, I want to move all .csv files from that directory to another directory.  (I can't just put the files in that other directory directly because of other issues.)

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "E:\CreditAdj\cashpost"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$Action = {Move-Item E:\CreditAdj\cashpost\*.csv \\server.company.com\cashpost}
$we1 = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier 
CashpostCreated -Action $Action
```

The first time I create file(s) in that directory, it behaves as expected.  All .csv files added to that directory are moved to the other directory.
I execute

```
$we1 |fl *
```

and the output shows no error.

The second time I create .csv file(s) in the directory, nothing happens, and $we1 |fl * has an error

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The third time I create .csv files in the directory, .csv files from the second attempt are moved, but not the newly created .csv files.

Comment: How are you creating the CSV files? I know that if you use Excel, it holds on to the file preventing it from being moved until Excel is either closed, or the file is closed (like if you close and create a new file).

Comment: In testing so far, I've just been dragging files around in File Explorer or moving files using PowerShell commands.  Ultimately, a C# application will drop the .csv files there.  That's a good pont to keep in mind though.